# Why an iptables NAT does not happen in the network namespace separated transparent proxy setup?

Tags: iptables, transparent-proxy, policy-routing, masquerade

I'm trying to setup transparent proxying networks on my host.

Real Client and Proxy targets are containters but in this experiment
I use netns (network namespace) separated envinroment.

To redirect client traffic to proxy transparently, I use policy routing.

```
 Client (C)         Proxy (P)
 10.10.1.1/24      10.10.2.1/24
     veth0             veth0
      |                 |
   veth pair         veth pair
      |                 |
  -----------(HOST)--------------
 client-veth0       proxy-veth0
 10.10.1.2/24      10.10.2.2/24
      |                 |            172.16.202.30
      +-----------------+-------------- enp4s0 ---- INTERNET

# Policy Routing on Host
# [Client->Proxy]
# ip rule:  from 10.10.1.0/24 iif client-veth0 lookup 100
# ip route: (100) default via 10.10.2.1 dev proxy-veth0
# [Proxy->Internet]
# ip route: (master) default via 172.16.202.1 dev enp4s0 proto static metric 100
# iptables: -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.1.1/32 -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
# [Internet->Proxy]
# ip rule:  from all to 10.10.1.0/24 iif enp4s0 lookup 100
# ip route: (100) default via 10.10.2.1 dev proxy-veth0
# [Proxy->Client]
# ip rule:  from all to 10.10.1.0/24 iif proxy-veth0 lookup 101
# ip route: (101) default via 10.10.1.1 dev client-veth0
```

Problem is, When I ping 8.8.8.8 from Client, within client netns, **source ip masquerading does not happen.**
iptables masquerade rule does not match and defaults to ACCEPT .
I expect that tcpdump on enp4s0 shows `172.16.202.30 --> 8.8.8.8`, but it shows `10.10.1.1 --> 8.8.8.8`, without source IP masquerading.

I recorded pcap on internet line to clarify SNAT does not occur. `client_to_goolge` is recorded from separate machine outside enp4s0:

```
$ tcpdump -r client_to_google -n
reading from file client_to_google, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
23:35:40.852257 IP 10.10.1.1 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 14867, seq 1, length 64
23:35:41.865269 IP 10.10.1.1 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 14867, seq 2, length 64
```

When I checked on iptables mangle table, packets flows by given policy:

```
  PREROUTING: client-veth0, 10.10.1.1 --> 8.8.8.8
  POSTROUTING: proxy-veth0, 10.10.1.1 --> 8.8.8.8
  PREROUTING: proxy-veth0, 10.10.1.1 --> 8.8.8.8
  POSTROUTING: enp4s0, 10.10.1.1 --> 8.8.8.8
```

However, when I change masquerade rule on `proxy-veth0` out interface, like this `iptables: -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.1/32 -o proxy-veth0 -j MASQUERADE`, masquerading happens. That is
`10.10.2.2 --> 8.8.8.8` packets are captured.

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
...
11       0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      enp4s0  10.10.1.1            0.0.0.0/0
12       1    84 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      proxy-veth0  10.10.1.1            0.0.0.0/0
```

Above table shows that rule #11 `enp4s0` output condition did not trigger. Rule #12 was inserted after several test with rule #11. Rule #12 shows that `proxy-veth0` output condition did trigger. Are there any differences between `enp4s0` master nic and `proxy-veth0` virthual interface with iptables?

Any comments will be appreciated deeply,
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to assume that the transparent proxy is acting as a router, at least for ICMP, so will route back the ICMP echo where it came from (*veth0*).

### Finding the problem

When reproducing your setup and witnessing your problem, I added a [TRACE](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#TRACE) on the host using *iptables* (legacy, which might have slight differences with [*iptables-nft*'s version](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-nft.8#DIFFERENCES_TO_LEGACY_IPTABLES)) like this (I also forced the creation of the filter table (`iptables -S`) to have it in the traces):

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j TRACE
```

And a single ping shows in kernel logs (hint, if *host* isn't the actual initial host: `sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_log_all_netns=1`):

```
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=client-veth0 OUT= MAC=66:f2:08:79:d0:df:be:1e:05:c1:c1:4b:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=7200 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=3508 SEQ=1 
TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=client-veth0 OUT= MAC=66:f2:08:79:d0:df:be:1e:05:c1:c1:4b:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=7200 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=3508 SEQ=1 
TRACE: filter:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=client-veth0 OUT=proxy-veth0 MAC=66:f2:08:79:d0:df:be:1e:05:c1:c1:4b:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=7200 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=3508 SEQ=1 
TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:policy:2 IN=client-veth0 OUT=proxy-veth0 MAC=66:f2:08:79:d0:df:be:1e:05:c1:c1:4b:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=7200 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=3508 SEQ=1 
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=proxy-veth0 OUT= MAC=16:c9:3c:d4:ad:8c:8a:84:06:5d:88:e2:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=7200 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=3508 SEQ=1 
TRACE: filter:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=proxy-veth0 OUT=enp4s0 MAC=16:c9:3c:d4:ad:8c:8a:84:06:5d:88:e2:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=7200 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=3508 SEQ=1
```

At the same time, having [`conntrack -E`](https://manpages.debian.org/conntrack.8) running on the host shows the matching:

```
# conntrack -E
    [NEW] icmp     1 30 src=10.10.1.1 dst=8.8.8.8 type=8 code=0 id=3508 [UNREPLIED] src=8.8.8.8 dst=10.10.1.1 type=0 code=0 id=3508
```

What happened:

- conntrack (which handles NAT) doesn't care about routes (eg: there's no interface in the conntrack database), only about addresses,
- the *nat* table will only see packets in NEW states,
- the time when *conntrack* added a NEW entry in its database was when the packet was routed from *client-veth0* to *proxy-veth0*: not matching the POSTROUTING rule,
- the second round when routing from *proxy-veth0* to *enp4s0* the packet matched an entry in *conntrack* and **the *nat* table was not called again**,
- packet leaves to Internet non-NATed.

Since this *conntrack*'s limitation hindered some use cases in the past, like yours, an additional feature was added:

### [conntrack zones](https://lwn.net/Articles/370152/)

> A zone is simply a numerical identifier associated with a network
>   device that is incorporated into the various hashes and used to
>   distinguish entries in addition to the connection tuples.
>
> [...]
>
> This is mainly useful when connecting multiple private networks using
>   the same addresses (which unfortunately happens occasionally) to pass
>   the packets through a set of veth devices and SNAT each network to a
>   unique address, after which they can pass through the "main" zone and
>   be handled like regular non-clashing packets and/or have NAT applied a
>   second time based f.i. on the outgoing interface.

It allows to sort-of duplicate the *conntrack* facility, including NAT handling, but has to be done manually and match the problem: here the routing topology.

So here the client <-> proxy traffic, in *conntrack*'s point of view, must be split from other traffic.

I would have preferred to also split the proxy <-> Internet traffic from the generic host traffic, but this is too difficult, because the *raw* table, where zones must be assigned to a packet, sees only the non-de-NATed traffic, so Internet replies will all arrive with destination 172.16.202.30). Anyway There's no duplicated flow here between both like with the client <-> proxy flow, so that's not really needed.

- zone 0 (0 means no special zone): generic host traffic
  along with proxy <-> Internet traffic.

  Nothing special to do, this is the default.
- zone 1: client <-> proxy traffic. The [`CT --zone`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#CT) target is used. The value here is chosen arbitrarily and not needed anywhere else for this case.

  ```
  iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i client-veth0 -j CT --zone 1
  iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i proxy-veth0 -d 10.10.1.0/24 -j CT --zone 1
  ```

The correct results (I merged both tools' outputs) are now:

```
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:rule:2 IN=client-veth0 OUT= MAC=4e:e7:2f:3f:a3:6c:4a:b9:40:66:60:32:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=58185 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:4 IN=client-veth0 OUT= MAC=4e:e7:2f:3f:a3:6c:4a:b9:40:66:60:32:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=58185 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=client-veth0 OUT= MAC=4e:e7:2f:3f:a3:6c:4a:b9:40:66:60:32:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=58185 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
TRACE: filter:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=client-veth0 OUT=proxy-veth0 MAC=4e:e7:2f:3f:a3:6c:4a:b9:40:66:60:32:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=58185 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:policy:2 IN=client-veth0 OUT=proxy-veth0 MAC=4e:e7:2f:3f:a3:6c:4a:b9:40:66:60:32:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=58185 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
    [NEW] icmp     1 30 src=10.10.1.1 dst=8.8.8.8 type=8 code=0 id=4079 [UNREPLIED] src=8.8.8.8 dst=10.10.1.1 type=0 code=0 id=4079 zone=1
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:4 IN=proxy-veth0 OUT= MAC=86:c8:4b:5f:16:fc:ba:76:80:0f:20:7d:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=58185 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
TRACE: nat:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=proxy-veth0 OUT= MAC=86:c8:4b:5f:16:fc:ba:76:80:0f:20:7d:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=58185 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
TRACE: filter:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=proxy-veth0 OUT=enp4s0 MAC=86:c8:4b:5f:16:fc:ba:76:80:0f:20:7d:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=58185 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:rule:1 IN=proxy-veth0 OUT=enp4s0 MAC=86:c8:4b:5f:16:fc:ba:76:80:0f:20:7d:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=58185 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
    [NEW] icmp     1 30 src=10.10.1.1 dst=8.8.8.8 type=8 code=0 id=4079 [UNREPLIED] src=8.8.8.8 dst=172.16.202.30 type=0 code=0 id=4079
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:4 IN=enp4s0 OUT= MAC=5e:e8:0c:bf:96:d9:b2:e7:bc:df:1f:8e:08:00 SRC=8.8.8.8 DST=172.16.202.30 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=62 ID=12099 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
TRACE: filter:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=enp4s0 OUT=proxy-veth0 MAC=5e:e8:0c:bf:96:d9:b2:e7:bc:df:1f:8e:08:00 SRC=8.8.8.8 DST=10.10.1.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=12099 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
 [UPDATE] icmp     1 30 src=10.10.1.1 dst=8.8.8.8 type=8 code=0 id=4079 src=8.8.8.8 dst=172.16.202.30 type=0 code=0 id=4079
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:rule:3 IN=proxy-veth0 OUT= MAC=86:c8:4b:5f:16:fc:ba:76:80:0f:20:7d:08:00 SRC=8.8.8.8 DST=10.10.1.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=60 ID=12099 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:4 IN=proxy-veth0 OUT= MAC=86:c8:4b:5f:16:fc:ba:76:80:0f:20:7d:08:00 SRC=8.8.8.8 DST=10.10.1.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=60 ID=12099 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
TRACE: filter:FORWARD:policy:1 IN=proxy-veth0 OUT=client-veth0 MAC=86:c8:4b:5f:16:fc:ba:76:80:0f:20:7d:08:00 SRC=8.8.8.8 DST=10.10.1.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=59 ID=12099 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=4079 SEQ=1 
 [UPDATE] icmp     1 30 src=10.10.1.1 dst=8.8.8.8 type=8 code=0 id=4079 src=8.8.8.8 dst=10.10.1.1 type=0 code=0 id=4079 zone=1
```

Here a single first packet from a new flow triggers twice iptables' *nat* table, the first time with no effect. Actually *conntrack* considers there are two flows, because the first flow has the additional attribute `zone=1`.

Comment: note: If you need proper direct client <-> host communication, you'll probably have to add exceptions in the CT rules (eg: `... -i client-veth0 ! -d 10.10.1.2 ...`   or, instead, the opposite, a `-t raw OUTPUT -o client-veth0` ), or host's firewall might not be happy.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your kind and complete answer. The only thing I managed to do myself  was doing `sysctl -w "net.netfilter.nf_log.2"=nf_log_ipv4` to enable netfliter logging on my machine. :-D

Comment: Getting traces and logs is often an issue with network namespaces, and it might even depend on the kernel version. Also using iptables-nft or nftables requires yet-an-other-method (which is certainly better) to get them.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal iptables NAT behavior. Testing right now with tcpdump, I use three virtual machines, on every virtual machine i set SNAT rule

vm1(10.10.1.1) ---> vm2(10.10.2.2) ---> vm3(1.2.3.4) (public ip address)

Then I try ping 8.8.8.8 from 10.10.1.1, run tcpdump on all three machines and results was next:
on vm2 10.10.1.1 ---> 8.8.8.8
on vm3 10.10.2.2 ---> 8.8.8.8

In theory if I have vm4 i would see 1.2.3.4 ---> 8.8.8.8

Could You please show your proxy config?

Boris

Comment: Thank you for kind note. However, when I capture from Internet line with additional machine, outgoing packet does not get masqueraded. The following is capture from internet: `$ tcpdump -r client_to_google -n
reading from file client_to_google, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
23:35:40.852257 IP 10.10.1.1 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 14867, seq 1, length 64
23:35:41.865269 IP 10.10.1.1 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 14867, seq 2, length 64`

Comment: proxy just forwards packet and does not do anything particular now.

Comment: what if you try iptables: -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE I know it's stupid maybe but try.

Comment: then masquerade happens at proxy-veth0 (10.10.2.2 --> 8.8.8.8), but i cannot find where the packet goes. pcap on enp4s0 (default route) does not show any.

Comment: Just for curiosity, you use static ip address or DHCP on enp4s0 ?

Comment: enp4s0 has static ip address. I tried with SNAT --to ipaddress, but same result

Comment: http://fosshelp.blogspot.com/2014/07/iptables-dnat-snat-masquerade-with.html   maybe you will found some information here.

Comment: also try SNAT rules in proxy-veth0 and enp4s0  interfaces concurrently.

Comment: Kindly refer @A.B's answer. It was conntrack I misssed: `the second round when routing from proxy-veth0 to enp4s0 the packet matched an entry in conntrack and the nat table was not called again`